# How to change Mysql DATE_FORMAT for table column in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

What is the equivalent cakephp find query for the following sql query?

Assume that **price_date field type is datetime**

```
$sql = "SELECT id,product_id,date_format("%Y-%m-%d",price_date) AS pd from products"
```

Not like this `$this->Product->query($sql);`

I want it like `$this->Product->find('...`

Comment: Next time, it's suggested you try something, do some research, show what you've tried...etc.

Comment: What do you mean by this question? "Change Mysql DATE_FORMAT for table column" then in description you ask an other thing "$this->Product->find"?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to define it as a [virtualField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) in your Product model:

```
class Product extends AppModel {

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'pd' => 'date_format(price_date, "%Y-%m-%d")'
    );

}
```

Then `price_date` will always return in Y-m-d format, aliased as `pd`, as if it were a field in your database. If you want it to return like that under another name, simply change the key in the array. Using it as a find, you can then simply:

```
$this->Product->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('id', 'product_id', 'pd')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->Product->find('all', array(
  'recursive' => -1,
  'fields' => array('id', 'product_id', 'date_format("%Y-%m-%d",price_date) AS pd from products')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify it in your `find()` fields array:

```
'fields' => array(
    //...
    'date_format("%Y-%m-%d", price_date)',
    //...
)
```